# How to select an element in SysTreeView using WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to select an element in a SysTreeView, right click it and select an element in the list which pops up.

To select an element I wrote:

```
Window = waitWindowEx(Window, NULL, "SysTreeView32", NULL); 

const int TV_FIRST = 0x1100; 
const int TVGN_ROOT = 0x0; 
const int TVGN_NEXT = 0x1; 
const int TVGN_CHILD = 0x4; 
const int TVGN_FIRSTVISIBLE = 0x5; 
const int TVGN_NEXTVISIBLE = 0x6; 
const int TVGN_CARET = 0x9; 
const int TVM_SELECTITEM = (TV_FIRST + 11); 
const int TVM_GETNEXTITEM = (TV_FIRST + 10); 
const int TVM_GETITEM = (TV_FIRST + 12); 

int treeItem = 0; 
treeItem = SendMessage(Window, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_ROOT, NULL);
SendMessage(Window, TVM_SELECTITEM, TVGN_CARET, (LPARAM)(treeItem));
```

Window is the handle after traversing to reach the tree (used Spy++)
but nothing happens on the screen. 
The tree is

```
-A
--A1
--A2
--A3
```

I am trying to select and right click A2.

Any help is appreciated.

Thnx

Comment: I suggest you to paste more code, so it will become more clear what you're doing.

Comment: Edited the original post with more info. Thanks.

Comment: The code works on my computer. If you're compiling for Win64, note that `treeItem` should be a 64-bit value, or `HTREEITEM` to be precise. Also note that your code selects `A`, not `A2`.

Comment: The code as shown will select A. To select A2 you would need to use `TVM_GETNEXTITEM` to get A's first child (A1) and then A1's next sibling (A2).

Comment: Also I suggest including `commctrl.h` instead of keying in those constants manually. I'm wondering why you want to select some foreign tree view element...

Comment: Any idea how could i click on an element in the pop up box which appears after i right click on A2? Unfortunately there are no short cut keys to get to that element. Hence i have to go through this pain of traversing the tree and right clicking element.

Comment: The UI of this tool application i am driving is such that some menu items are listed in a tree view. The only way to access them is to get through that tree. I am wondering how can I get the handle of that list/box  which pops up after right clicking an element. It does not even show up in spy++ because the list disappears after I click outside it.

Comment: Have a look with Spy++ at what messages the window receives when you select an item from that menu. If it gets a `WM_COMMAND` message and the ID is the same every time (I.e. the menu isn't dynamic) then you should be able to post that message to the parent window to simulate the menu selection.

Comment: The application has disabled logging messages. I dont see any messages in spy++ on any activity on that application.

Comment: Oh, not again. Wouldn't it just be so much easier to use UIautomation?